# How do I access the database from a stand-alone PHP script?

Tags: external-scripts

I have problems to define the right path to the root and bootstrap data in php.

My structure (Windows) looks like the following.

- C:\xmapp\

  - htdocs\

    - testdrupal\

      - test.php
  - includes\

    - bootstrap.inc
  - sites\

    - default\

      - settings.php

The content of the test.php file is the following.

```
<?php

  chdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\');
  // Bootstrap Drupal up through the database phase.
  include_once('./includes/bootstrap.inc');
  drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
?>
```

When I run it, I get the following error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\test.php

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a standalone script? If it's for something that's access through the browser, write a module. For a script that is executed on the console, I recommend looking into writing drush commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly bootstrap drupal for standalone PHP file?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/properly-bootstrap-drupal-for-standalone-php-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As reported in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), "[to] specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\)." In the string you wrote (`'C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\'`) the single quote character is escaped, which means you are saying to PHP "this is not the string delimiter; it is part of the string."

The string that PHP sees is the following one.

```
'C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\');
// Bootstrap Drupal up through the database phase.
include_once('
```

When it parses the rest of the code, it finds the `.` which is the string concatenation operator, and a slash, which doesn't have any meaning for PHP at that point, as it is expecting a literal string, a constant name, a variable name, or a function/method call.

The second error you get about an undefined constant (`DRUPAL_ROOT`) is because Drupal 7 uses that constant, but the code you are using to bootstrap Drupal doesn't define it. See the code in the [index.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/index.php/7) file to understand where to define that constant and which value to assign it.

```
/**
 * Root directory of Drupal installation.
 */
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Drupal 7 doesn't rely on the current directory to find the directory where it has been installed, but it uses that constant every time it includes a PHP file. That is what [`module_include_file()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) does, for example.

```
function module_load_include($type, $module, $name = NULL) {
  if (!isset($name)) {
    $name = $module;
  }

  if (function_exists('drupal_get_path')) {
    $file = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . drupal_get_path('module', $module) . "/$name.$type";
    if (is_file($file)) {
      require_once $file;
      return $file;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Your code should be similar to the following one.

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal');

// Bootstrap Drupal up through the database phase.
 require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the first line (where you have `..testdrupal\'`);

The `\` before the `'` is escaping the `'` so it's as if it's not there (sorry, it's tricky to explain without my morning coffee).

With the character escaped, the line is being read as follows:

`chdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal'./includes/bootstrap.inc');`

Which is where your error is most likely coming from.

Try changing the first line to the following:

```
chdir('C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\\');
```

The extra `\` means that you are escaping the following character so the line will be read the way you want it to be.

There's a quick explanation of escape characters [here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer...now it grives me more errors: Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: No such file or directory (errno 2); Notice: Use of undefined constant DRUPAL_ROOT - assumed 'DRUPAL_ROOT' in C:\xampp\htdocs\testdrupal\includes\bootstrap.inc on line 2203 .... i guess its more the second part with the include once ??