# How to render a Drupal 7 field in stand alone PHP file?

Tags: entities, ajax, javascript

Hi this is probably a really basic question, but hopefully you guys can help me out...

I have a javascript client application (Separate to my main Drupal 7 website) and rather than maintaining a duplicate select list with a large number of values, I would like to use an AJAX call to a PHP file on the Drupal server which will render the HTML for the list I need.

The list is configured as a custom field (Text List type).

Can I create a PHP file in the root of the website, and include the required module files?

An example would be fantastic!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could definitely [bootstrap Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/properly-bootstrap-drupal-for-standalone-php-file) in a standalone file, but if you're doing it inside the same document root as the Drupal installation you'd be better off implementing a custom menu path in a module, and using the callback for that path to output the necessary value.

If you print directly from a page callback function and don't return anything, the standard theme wrappers won't be included and you'll just be left with the value you've printed.

A basic example might look like this:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['custom-path'] = array(
    'title' => 'Custom page', // Required, won't actually be displayed anywhere
    'access arguments' => array('access content'), 
    // 'access callback' => TRUE, // This is an alternative to the access arguments if you don't need any access control for this path
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_ajax_page',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_ajax_page() {
  $output = function_to_produce_field_output();

  print $output;
}
```

After you clear Drupal's caches any request for http://mysite.com/custom-path should produce the un-themed results from your page callback; you can then use that path as your AJAX callback.

You might also want to look at [`drupal_add_http_header()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_add_http_header/7) to set an appropriate content type before you print the output.

As far as getting the field output goes, it's a bit of a pain but this should work:

```
$entity_type = 'user';
$bundle = 'user';
$field_name = 'field_field_name';

// Get field info for the allowed values
$field_info = field_info_field($field_name);

// Get instance info for label/required/description/default value
$field_instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

// Build the select list
$select = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#value' => $field_instance['default_value'],
  '#options' => $field_info['settings']['allowed_values'],
  '#required' => $field_instance['required']
);

// Build the element wrapper
$wrapper = array(
  '#title' => t($field_instance['label']),
  '#description' => t($field_instance['description']),
  '#children' => theme('select', array('element' => $select))
);

// Get the fully rendered element
$rendered = theme('form_element', array('element' => $wrapper));

print $rendered;
```

Comment: Good answer, but I'm not so sure about the access_callback comment. Why would you create open doors with ajax calls? IMO they should be protected as any other resource, so probably the same as the page that normally calls the given ajax call.

Comment: @fietserwin It's pretty common practice; the core filter, image, locale, openid, system, update and user modules all use it (as well as a ton of contrib modules). But yeah, setting `access arguments` instead is just as good (maybe better), depends on your use case I guess

Comment: Thanks, @Clive, that makes total sense. And I agree this is just rendering a simple Select List with no sensitive data inside it, so security isn't an issue.

Comment: @Clive I just tried to vote-up your answer, but don't have enough reputation yet (Newb on this forum)

Comment: @Darren Thanks but don't worry about that, I'm not bothered about the reputation :) What I'm worried about is this moron giving real users of this site the impression that correct answers are actually incorrect. Glad it helped either way :)

Comment: @Clive Here, have an upvote for a good answer.  Same thing happened to me  few months back.

Comment: @Chapabu Thanks dude :) I'll come find you and buy you a pint next time I'm over in Falmer (I'm just down the road in Lewes)

Comment: @Clive he..I live in Uckfield, but I tend to always head to the Dorset or Snowdrop in Lewes if I head out!  Small world.  Pint is a definite at some point though :-)

Comment: @Chapabu Nice! I stay away from the Dorset because of the scary German bar tender (she kept talking to me about falconry and horse whispering...seriously). But next time you're over gimmie a shout!

Comment: Sorry to interrupt @Clive, The bar tender in the Dorset sounds mental ;) Anyhoo, I've now got my menu working, calling a function in my custom module, but I'm still stuck on how to render the raw HTML for a field (There is no $node or $entity context so I'm not sure how I can easily render the HTML for the field).

Comment: Heh no worries, you'll have to come down for a drink :P So yeah, you'll need to get some context to that script somehow...is it being called from a node page? I'm thinking you could tack `?nid=123` on to the end of the URL then check `$_GET['nid']` in the script

Comment: Beer sounds good - but I'm up in the East midlands, so its a bit of a trek! The URL I created is being called by a totally separate web app, which needs the same select list as the one configured in Drupal against a User's Profile. However there is no specific user so I just want to render the list. Maybe I need to load a dummy user to get this working?

Comment: Ah well another time! Thinking about it, you won't need to load a dummy user as you can get what you need with the field metadata and some theme functions. I've added some code to the answer, it should do the trick

Comment: @Clive I've got some contact info on my bio - hit me with some contact details :)

Comment: and @Darren - I'm sure you could make it down South at some point ;-)

Comment: @clive thanks! That has worked perfectly. Seems a bit of an overhead to just render a field, but it will save me maintaining the list in 3 different systems!