# Problem getting Drupal SESSION value from standalone php page in subdirectory

Tags: sessions

Last 2 days I am searching for solution on Internet. I have a module in my drupal site's "sites/all/modules" folder named "coupon".I added a new test.php file in the "coupon" folder which has no relation with drupal. I can't access Drupal's session from this file.Below is my code wrote in test.php which I find on net.It is giving result, but not the right one.

```
<?php
$path = getcwd();
$pos = strpos($path, 'sites');
$path = substr($path, 0, $pos);
$path = explode('\\', $path);

$length = sizeof($path);
unset($path[$length - 1]);
$path = implode('/', $path);

// Get the base path
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $path);

//Include the bootstrap file for using the DRUPLA function in our file
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
// Bootstrap Drupal at the phase that you need
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
// Our custom page now has access to Drupal functions
// such as node_load() and db_query()
$node = node_load(1);
global $user;

var_dump($user);
?>
```

when I run the test.php file it is giving following result:

```
object(stdClass)[7]
  public 'uid' => int 0
  public 'hostname' => string '::1' (length=3)
  public 'roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      1 => string 'anonymous user' (length=14)
  public 'cache' => int 0
```

But I am currently login with username "test" whose uid is '3' and also 'roles' is 'admin'. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [user not logged in php file](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/124286/user-not-logged-in-php-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properly bootstrap drupal for standalone PHP file?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/properly-bootstrap-drupal-for-standalone-php-file)