# How do you get DRUPAL_ROOT when using it in a separate php file?

Tags: external-scripts

It has been covered many many times on several sites, explaining how to define DRUPAL_ROOT and bootstrap the page (whatever that actually means). However no one has ever said how to use it in a separate PHP file.

I am trying to use a php file as my data layer in a custom module. However when I use define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()) it comes back with the directory of the module (as expected). 
If I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] it comes back with the www HTML folder and not my drupal install folder.

If I add .base_path() it doesnt know what the hell that is! 
I can't just had code it because it's going to another IT team and I have no idea what their file structure is like.

Please, can anyone help! I am going insane!!

Its just a standard php file with some db_query's in. This really can't be as hard as I'm making it, can it?

Comment: Are you making a module or trying to have a completely separate php page that accesses Drupal in some way?

Comment: It's supposed to be a module that exports data from the database to Microsoft Word. However my manager insisted that I break all of the code out into separate php and inc files so there is nothing in the .module file.

Would this make a difference as to why it doesn't understand DRUPAL_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use **DRUPAL_ROOT** instead of trying to define it in your php file?

**DRUPAL_ROOT** is already available at this point and it contains the path to your Drupal installation.

For example:

> watchdog('testlog', DRUPAL_ROOT . 'test');

Comment: Thanks @sshrestha . However I tried using just DRUPAL_ROOT as: require_once DRUPAL_ROOT. '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; and it gave the error: Warning: require_once(DRUPAL_ROOT/includes/bootstrap.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if it makes a difference that it is not in the module file. –

Comment: @James I hate to be pedantic, but if what you typed in is verbatim command, then it is a syntax error. It should be require_once(__ROOT__.'/config.php');
Just want to make sure its not something that simple before thinking too far ahead.

Comment: Just tried require_once(ROOT.'/config.php') and that doesn't work either, as well as (DRUPAL_ROOT.'/config.php')

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the DRUPAL_ROOT constant to point to the folder where your drupal installation is (in other words, on same folder where the index.php is located)

[The bootstrap phase](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_bootstrap/7) that you need load will depend on what do you need to do on your separated php script (db queries, session handling, multilanguage, ...).

[On this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28511/properly-bootstrap-drupal-for-standalone-php-file#answer-28520) you can see a small example on what I think you are looking to implement.

If you don't know where is going to be installed the Drupal site on other environments, you could use a relative path to define it, for example, if your script it's located in a module with this path:

```
sites/all/modules/custom/my_module
```

And your site has the same architecture on the other environments, you could set the DRUPAL_ROOT like this:

```
$drupaldir = realpath('../../../../../');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $drupaldir);
```

It's not elegant but it should work on any environment no matter on which folder is the drupal site.

Comment: Thanks @gerzenstl, however they have used "define('DRUPAL_ROOT', '/var/www/clients/client1/web15/web');" to define where the index.php is. I have done this and it works fine but as its going to another IT team that deals with many many drupal sites, I dont know what their file structure is like and therefore how to define it.

I would ask them but they seem to get really stroppy if you ask them what seem to be really stupid questions.

Comment: It's not a stupid question to ask about where is located the index.php of a Drupal site/multisite installation. It's very hard to guess if all those sites are on a same location on the structure folder.

Comment: If you have access to one of those sites as an admin user, you could go to admin/reports/status/php and check the DOCUMENT_ROOT value.