# Using Drupal's session inside a PHP script

Tags: sessions

I need to pass parameters from a Drupal page to a PHP script.
There's no way to pass that directly and I need to use SESSIONS.
I've searched around and added this at the top of the script:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_SESSION);
```

With that I can use Drupal's session but I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

It's not so bad since it's just a warning and I can use CSS to make it not visible to the user. But I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do so.

Comment: Can the PHP script not be a Drupal module?

Comment: Unfortunately no...
It's a script for credit card company and i must do what they say...

Comment: Have you tried not bootstrapping Drupal and just trying to print_r($_SESSION); to see if what you need is in there?

Comment: of course...thats the first thing i did.

Comment: are you including anything above the code you provided? Maybe another include/require is printing out a header.

Comment: no... i've put it just beloew the "?<php" tag... the problem is that its a script inside an iframe inside a drupal form. so i'm guessing that the problem is that the drupal page is already started the session and when i bootsrtap it again in the iframe it gives me that warnings

Comment: This question may be answered elsewhere: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79807/loading-bootstrap-inc-in-external-php-file-in-a-subdirectory

Comment: Also similar to this one: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/22740/10729

Answer (score 1):

In instances where I've had to do things like this I've done the following. It's worked for D6/D7 without any warnings for me.

```
  $current_path = getcwd(); //Current app path

  //Remove any HTTP headers/output
  header_remove();
  ob_clean();

  //Bootstrap Drupal w/ dir change 
  //$drupal_root being the root Drupal install path
  define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $drupal_root);
  chdir($drupal_root);
  require_once "$drupal_root/includes/bootstrap.inc";

  /*Execute Code Dependant on Drupal Environment */

  chdir($current_path); //Return to existing app path
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you do not print anything to the output buffer (with functions like echo or print) before setting/defining headers (with functions like header)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i cannot control this... i'm a regular drupal page(hook_menu) and in this page i've put an iframe with the php script... so basically drupal bootstrap runs twice and i'm guessing this is the problem but i don't know how to solve this

Comment: Try to add ob_start(); directly after the 3 lines you posted, this will start another output buffer preventing to send headers

Comment: Nope, this didn't do the trick...

Comment: Why are you starting drupal bootstrap in your script if it is already started before ?? You shouldn't need to do this.